# Listing all bibtex keys (NOT in LaTeX)

Tags: bibtex

I have a bib file with 1,579 entries. This is being read by another (non-LaTeX) system, which I have just recently discovered has opinions about the key: e.g. all - and _ elements are removed. I would like to generate a list of all the bib keys in my file, and would like to avoid writing a home-spun RegEx if at all possible. Is there support within BibTeX for just getting a list of all the keys in a file, so I can target the offending ones?

Comment: I did not test, but the `citekeys` from https://ctan.org/pkg/bibtools sounds as if it might be what you are looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`bibtool` program](https://ctan.org/pkg/bibtool?lang=en) (which is distinct from the `bibtools` bundle in the other answer) can do what you want.   To list all entries whose key includes `-` you can run

`bibtool -i <bibname.bib> -- 'select.by.string{$key "-"}'`

If you want to just print the key and and not other fields, you can pipe the output of the previous command to

`bibtool -- 'keep.field{$key}'`

---

But if you are using an external tool **and** that you are open to changing the citation keys so that the external tool will not complain (and you have no requirements to maintain compatibility with an existing TeX document using those citation keys), you can just ask `bibtool` to normalize the citation keys instead of editing them yourself. See section A.10 in the program manual for details.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in a comment the `citekeys` shell script from the `bibtools` collection does exactly this. If it is not installed you can download the two files of the script (`citekeys` and `citekeys.bst`) from https://ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/utils/bibtools.

Unfortunately the script is written for csh/tcsh with some specific syntax, so it does not work for bash/dash (which I tried) and probably also not with zsh, ksh etc (which I did not try).

Below a simplified version where I stripped the parts that use csh syntax, which are the support for multiple bib files and a cleanup routine to remove extra files. You still need `citekeys.bst` for this that can be downloaded from the url above.

```bash
#!/bin/sh -f
#
# citekeys - print out all the cite keys in given bib files
#
# simplified version, adapted from http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/utils/bibtools/citekeys
#
# usage: 
#    citekeys file.bib
#

cat > citekeys.aux <<EOF
\relax 
\citation{*}
\bibstyle{citekeys}
\bibdata{$1}
EOF
bibtex citekeys
rm citekeys.blg
```

Save as, e.g., `citekeyssimple`, make executable (`chmod +x citekeyssimple`) and call with `./citekeyssimple yourbibfile.bib`. Afterwards all cite keys from that bib file are listed in the file `citekeys.bbl`.

Example using `biblatex-examples.bib` which comes pre-installed with LaTeX distributions and is therefore already in the path:

```bash
./citekeyssimple biblatex-examples.bib
```

Result (first 10 lines shown, the full output is 92 lines):

```
aksin
almendro
angenendt
aristotle:anima
aristotle:physics
aristotle:poetics
aristotle:rhetoric
augustine
averroes/bland
averroes/hannes
```